# Photon Voice 2 isn't working on Microsoft HoloLens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, photon, windows-mixed-reality

I'm working on a mixed reality application. In which I'm applying voice chat/communication between multiple users using Photon Voice 2. Which I've imported from Unity Asset Store. I've followed below documentation: https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/voice/current/getting-started/voice-for-pun
This is properly working in unity. Means unity-to-unity it is working fine. But when I deployed it on HoloLens somehow it is not working. I'm not able to do voice chat in HoloLens2. I've imported MRKT Microphone Stream Selector package. Could you please help me out what setting I should do?

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior.

Photon Voice 2 only supports HoloLens 2 with a special addOn package, which is only available to Photon Industries Circle members.

You need to request membership to the Photon Industries circle at https://www.photonengine.com/en-US/Industries to get access to the Photon Voice 2HoloLens addOn Package.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I'm a bit confused here. Whether do I need to go for a gaming circle membership : https://www.photonengine.com/en-us/gaming or need to go for industrial one which you've mentioned?

Comment: AFAIK HoloLens 2 is only available in the Industries Circle as it's considered a device that is primarily used for B2B and not so much in the consumer market. However in doubt you can always just ask by email (either send an email to the address listed at https://www.photonengine.com/en-US/contact or to the one behind the 'get in contact' button at https://www.photonengine.com/en-US/Industries).